Borel-Cantelli lemma in the branching processes
I was reading GTM 295, Measure Theory, Probability and Stochastic Process by Le Gall. In the section 12.3, page 269, the second example, branching processes, where the author denote $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ as the Galton-Wastson process with offspring distribution $\mu$, provided $m = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\,\mu(k)$. And $m^{-n}Z_n$ is a nonnegative martingale w.r.t a specific filtration, hence converges a.s.
My question is in the case when $m =1$. The author claim that, for every $p\ge1$
$$
\mathbb{P}(\exists N\ge1:\forall n\ge N, Z_n = p)=0 
$$
i.e. The population becomes extinct a.s.
He said it can be obtained by a straightforward application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, which I find is confused.
Obviously, I notice that the event above is a "lim inf", and "lim inf" is the subset of "lim sup". If I apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma here, I need to verify the condition $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(Z_n = p) <\infty$, which seems to be a contradiciton.

Assuming that the number of offsprings is truly random (otherwise $Z_n=Z_0$ for all $n\ge 1$), we immediately get that
$$
\mathbb{P}(Z_{n}\ne p\mid Z_{n-1}=p)=\epsilon_p>0
$$
(for example, since $m=1$ and the process is non-degenerate, with a positive probability everyone of $p$ particles can have zero children).
Fix an $N\ge 0$. Then for $n\ge N$
$$
\mathbb{P}(A_{n})=(1-\epsilon_p)^{n-N}
$$
where
$$
A_{n}=\{Z_N=Z_{N+1}=...=Z_n=p\}
$$
Since $\sum_n (1-\epsilon_p)^{n-N}<\infty$  by the Borel-Cantelli lemma only finitely many of $A_n$ occcur.
Now the above statement is true for each $N$ which finishes the proof.
